# CPLEX can't find a solution if I use binary vabriables

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, cplex, mixed-integer-programming

I'm using CPLEX 12.9 with Python to solve a MILP (Mixed-Integer Linear Problem).
I tried two approaches; I expected the same results, but while the first approach works, the second doesn't.

**1) First approach:**

This approach **works successfully**. In the generated ".lp" file (a text file which contains a human-readable formulation of the problem: there's an objective function which has to be minimized and some constraints) it can be seen that `x6, x7, x8, x9, x10, x11` are `continuous` variables and all of them are equal to `500` (I defined both their `upper` and `lower` bounds equal to `500`; so they're effectively constants).

**2) Second approach:**

It returns `CPLEX Error  1217: No solution exists`, so CPLEX isn't able to find a solution, but I can't understand why.

The only things that I changed are:

- I setted `x6, x7, x8, x9, x10, x11` as `binary` variables;
- for each of them, I defined the `lower` bound equal to `0` and the `upper` bound equal to `500`.

So, the generated ".lp" file is very similar to the one generated by using the first approach; the only different things are that:

- `x6, x7, x8, x9, x10, x11` are defined as ranges (instead of constants), so they are:

  ```
  0 <= x6 <= 500
  0 <= x7 <= 500
  0 <= x8 <= 500
  0 <= x9 <= 500
  0 <= x10 <= 500
  0 <= x11 <= 500
  ```
- the `Binaries` section (at the end of the ".lp" file) now contains `x6, x7, x8, x9, x10, x11` variables, too.

**Note:**
Even if (in the second approach) I set both `lower` and `upper` bounds equal to `500`, the problem would persists.

Comment: binary implies lowerbound=0 and upperbound=1.

Comment: Thank you! I read [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/FileFormats/topics/LP_MIP.html) that `"Binary variables are automatically given bounds of 0 (zero) and 1 (one), unless alternative bounds are specified in the BOUNDS section, in which case a warning message is issued."`. So, at first, I thought that using non-default values for binary variable bounds would only generate a warning and that, CPLEX would have worked as expected, anyway. Instead, it seems that CPLEX doesn't really allow bounds different from 0/1 for binary variables.

Comment: I think you can use bounds to fix (binary) variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use binary that means the decision variable will either be 0 or 1 even if you later add some constraint that this should be less than 500.

If you want your decision variable to allow 500 as a value you should either use float or integer as type.

If I use the [zoo example](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zoodocplex/blob/master/zoo.py) and change integer to binary:

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model

mdl = Model(name='buses')
nbbus40 = mdl.binary_var(name='nbBus40')
nbbus30 = mdl.binary_var(name='nbBus30')
mdl.add_constraint(nbbus40*40 + nbbus30*30 >= 300, 'kids')
mdl.minimize(nbbus40*500 + nbbus30*400)

mdl.solve()

print(mdl.solve_details.status)
```

gives:

```
integer infeasible
```

Comment: I read [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/FileFormats/topics/LP_MIP.html) that `"Binary variables are automatically given bounds of 0 (zero) and 1 (one), unless alternative bounds are specified in the BOUNDS section, in which case a warning message is issued."`. So, at first, I thought that using non-default values for binary variable bounds would only cause a warning, but CPLEX would have worked as expected. Instead, it seems that CPLEX doesn't really allow bounds different from 0/1 for binary variables. BTW, now I solved, thank you!